# Should I worry about this foundation crack?

Tags: foundation, crack

The pictured crack in my house’s foundation runs along approx 80% of the side of the garage.  The house is from approx 1965
Is this a concern that I should hire a structural engineer for ?

[image]
[image: continuation]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Settlements might have occurred. If the interior floor remains level and no defects on the walls, suggest performing a level survey around the house against a permanent benchmark, and backcheck periodically. If the building interior shows distress/defects, call a structural, or geotechnical engineer.

Comment: I would want to seal it up to prevent any additional possible frost heave a quality latex concrete sealer should help keep moisture out. As concrete ages it gets brittle the rebar in the foundation helps to keep things together, keeping moisture out extends the life of the rebar and reduces the chances from frost or  insect home building damage.